# How to solve this arithmetic sequence with distance $a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be an arithmetic sequence with distance $a$.  Find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sqrt{a_{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{2}}+\sqrt{a_{3}}}+\dotsb +\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}\right).$$

I don't know how to solve it. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_{i+1}}} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_{i+1}}} \frac{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_i}}{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_i}} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_i}}{a} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_1}}{a} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sqrt{a_1+na}-\sqrt{a_1}}{a} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{na}{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1+na}+\sqrt{a_1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{a_1+na}+\sqrt{a_1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a_1}{n}+a}+\sqrt{\frac{a_1}{n}}} 
\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Rationalize it in such a way that you get the Common difference of this AP in the denominator. And due to this rationalization the numerator will have all of its term cancelled out except the first and last then you can take the limit. Try this and lemme know if it works or not.

Comment: Can you start only the beginning because I don't know what exactly to do?